# logging to file gnome-terminal output

Tags: bash, logging, gnome-terminal

I have a bash script where I use

```
gnome-terminal -e /folder/script1 &
gnome-terminal -e /folder/script2 &
```

to open two new terminals and carry out two parallel jobs.

I want to know if it is possible to log the output of these scripts by using something like

```
gnome-terminal -e /folder/script1 2>&1 | tee script1.log
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried that? Also, `2>&1` is the old syntax. I prefer `&>`.

Comment: @Blender `2>&1` is the portable syntax, `&>` is a bash extension.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but is not working.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "/folder/script1 2>&1 | tee /tmp/script1.log"'
```

---

Explanation:

```
gnome-terminal -e /folder/script1 2>&1
```

opens a gnome-terminal, executes `/folder/script1`, and directs stderr *of the gnome-terminal command* to stdout. To redirect stderr of `script1` to stdout, we need a shell. The same goes for `| tee /tmp/script1.log`.

Comment: nice! +1 but may I know why is bash -c need to specified explicitly? Isn't the shebang inside the script is sufficient?

Comment: @Jasonw: I've added an explanation to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @unutbu: Is this command useful when a variable is involved? For example,
$variable = YES
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "/folder/script1 $variable 2>&1 | tee /tmp/script1.log"'

Comment: Try:
    `variable=YES gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '/folder/script1 $variable 2>&1 | tee /tmp/script1.log'"`. (Reverse the order of the single- and double-quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this as well close to the top of the script that you are calling.  This way you will not have to | tee

```
exec >> ${LOGNAME} 2>&1
```